# Check if file is in a folder with a certain name before proceeding

Tags: bash, find

So, I have this simple script which converts videos in a folder into a format which the R4DS can play.

```
#!/bin/bash
scr='/home/user/dpgv4/dpgv4.py';mkdir -p 'DPG_DS'
find '../Exports' -name "*1080pnornmain.mp4" -exec python3 "$scr" {} \;
```

The problem is, some of the videos are invalid and won't play, and I've moved those videos to a different directory inside the Exports folder. What I want to do is check to make sure the files are in a folder called `new` before running the python script on them, preferably within the find command. The path should look something like this:

> ../Exports/(anything here)/new/*1080pnornmain.mp4

Please note that `(anything here)` text does not indicate a single directory, it could be something like `foo/bar`, `foo/b/ar`, `f/o/o/b/a/r`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `-name` because the search is on the path now. My first solution was:

```
find ./Exports -path '**/new/*1080pnornmain.mp4' -exec python3 "$scr" {} \;
```

But, as @dan pointed out in the comments, it is wrong because it uses the globstar wildcard (`**`) unnecessarily:

> This checks if `/new/` is somewhere in the preceding path, it doesn't have to be a direct parent.

So, the star is not enough here. Another possibility, using `find` only, could be this one:

```
find ./Exports -regex '.*/new/[^\/]*1080pnornmain.mp4' -exec python3 "$scr" {} \;
```

This regex matches:

1. any number of nested folders before `new` with `.*/new`
2. any character (except `/` to leave out further subpaths) + your filename with `[^\/]*1080pnornmain.mp4`

Performances could degrade given that it uses regular expressions.

---

Generally, instead of using the `-exec` option of the `find` command, you should opt to passing each line of `find` output to `xargs` because of the more efficient thread spawning, like:

```
find ./Exports -regex '.*/new/[^\/]*1080pnornmain.mp4' | xargs -0 -I '{}' python3 "$scr" '{}'
```

Comment: This checks if `/new/` is somewhere in the preceding path, it doesn't have to be a direct parent. Also, double asterisks is not necessary (a single one is correct), you are probably confusing with bash globstar.